# entity framework dbset which models?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using entity framework 6 and mvc 5, assuming I have the following models:

```
class Employee 
{
   public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public Department Department { get; set; }
}

class Department 
{
   public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
   public String DepartmentName { get; set; }
   public int FloorNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In my `DbContext` class where the `DbSet` goes, do I do `DbSet<Employee>` only or do I also have to do `DbSet<Department>`? Right now I'm only doing `DbSet<Employee>` because the way I understand it, the main model is `Employee` which has a complex type `Department` inside, so theoretically if `Employee` loads then Department should load passively (load as in create a table)?

Currently, I have `Department` as a `virtual` field for lazy loading because when I try to access it without the `virtual` attribute I get a `null pointer exception`.

Also, my model is a little more complex than this with multiple complex objects, do each of these need their own `DbSet`?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj679962.aspx) (emphasis is mine):

> **Type Discovery**
>
> <snip>
>
> In the following example, there is only one DbSet property defined on
>   the SchoolEntities class (Departments). **Code First uses this property
>   to discover and pull in any referenced types.**

However, if you ever wish to manipulate lists of `Employee`s independent from your `Department`, then you should include it.

Comment: thank you for the answer, however, there is no inheritance between the employee and the department, department is just a complex object inside the employee model/object. Does the behavior differ here?

Comment: The docs about inheritance are not relevant, I've snipped them out.